# Update panel in IE 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, updatepanel

I have create a sample program in Asp.net which updates time on a button click. This time is shown in a label. Button and and label both are inside update panel say upd1. 
Following is the aspx code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function fnhn() {

    __doPostBack("upd1","");
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods ="true"  >    </asp:ScriptManager> 
<div>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat ="server" ><ContentTemplate > 
 <asp:label runat="server" id="lbl_c" ></asp:label>
  <asp:button runat="server" id="btn_b" Text="Click" />
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:updatepanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

and following is the source code.

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    lbl_c.Text = Date.Now.ToString
End Sub
End Class
```

Now problem which i facing is as follows. I am able to update this time on button click without any postback in any browser other than IE 10. In IE10 my whole page gets refresh. which I obviously dont want to happen. Plz help me guys.

In a thread I also come to know about up leveling the user agent of IE10 through following.

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Request.UserAgent.ToLower.ToString.Contains("msie 10.0") Then
        Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel"
    End If
End Sub
```

Which didnt help me to come out of this issue.
Any comment suggestion and solution is valuable.

Comment: `If Request.UserAgent.ToLower.ToString.Contains("msie 10.0")` .... Warning: Be **very** cautious about using the User Agent string to identify a browser. It is considered bad practice to use this for anything important, because the UA string can lie to you because it's under the control of the user. Also, the IE11 UA string is completely different, so your check there won't work when your users upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your IE10 is allowing cookies? If you disabled cookies at some point the session would not be working (if cookie based) and therefore the AJAX would cause a full postback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the EnablePartialRendering?  This should be the default, but may be overridden elsewhere.

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
            EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```